# Join Battlefield Clan from Different Platforms

Tags: battlefield-4

Can't seem to find the answer to this online.
In 'Battlefield 4', is there any way to join a clan from different platforms?

For example, I'm using a PS3 and a friend is using a PC. Can we both join the same clan?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean a platoon?